# PNG разбор Chunks

Tags: python, python-3.x, png

Пишу программу по разбору chunks в png, подскажите, пожалуйста, как устроен chunk idata? И если применяется сжатие chunk, то каким модулем в Python3 можно воспользоваться для его разжатия?

Comment: А какой алгоритм сжатия используется в PNG? (hint: см. документацию)

Comment: Чанк [idat](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/236813/Чанк-idat-формата-png/772266)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можете посмотреть в исходники библиотеки [PyPNG](https://github.com/jcrocholl/pypng/blob/master/lib/png.py) где реализовано чтение/запись в PNG на чистом питоне. Там есть универсальный метод `Reader.read_chank()`, который читает чанк и возвращает его тип и данные, и метод `Reader.read()` где реализован весь алгоритм парсинга и распаковки картинки.

Ключевой момент распаковки данных заключён вот тут:

```
scanlines = array('B', zlib.decompress(''.join(compressed)))
if interlaced:
    pixels = self.deinterlace(scanlines)
else:
    pixels = self.read_flat(scanlines)
```

(в переменной `compressed` лежат сырые данные из всех чанков `IDAT`).

Из приведенного примера, не сложно догадаться, что модуль для распаковки данных называется zlib.