# Как прочитать метки из Png файла в С++?

Tags: c++, изображения, png, exif

Сейчас работаю над одной программой, которая считывает файл, а именно изображение (формата PNG), и мне нужно вытащить некую информацию оттуда (такую как signature, IDAT, IHDR, IEND, CRC). И вот я все ищу, как это сделать и что лучше использовать при работе. Какая библиотека нужна, какие функции из нее взять? Как вытащить оттуда нужную мне информацию?

Comment: libpng подойдет?

Comment: @Эникейщик, где написано, что надо распознать текст?  IDAT, IHDR, IEND, CRC - это всё информация о изображении

Comment: http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/libpng-1.2.5-manual.html#section-3.6 - весь запрашиваемый набор

Comment: @Эникейщик IDAT, etc - это части файла (critical chunks) в формате PNG, а CRC - контрольная сумма изображения. Где Вы увидели распознавание текста в вопросе ТС'а? О формате PNG: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Network_Graphics

Comment: @Croessmah Ок, я подумал, что там изображения/сканы каких-нибудь документов с даннными, которые нужно достать. Если нужно просто взять части файла, то упоминание того, что это изображение, излишне.

Comment: Посмотроите это http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/236813/%d0%a7%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%ba-idat-%d1%84%d0%be%d1%80%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b0-png/772266#772266 ответ

Comment: Вы можете читать 4 байта сигнатура 2 байта размер чанка. Описание чанков есть на libpng.org

Answer (score 2):

Вы можете установить библиотеку libpng, как Вам посоветовал @Croessmah, и если Вы привыкли писать на Си - то на этом можно и остановиться.

Если же для Вас более удобен C++ - установите библиотеку [png++](http://savannah.nongnu.org/projects/pngpp). Это библиотека предоставляет C++-интерфейс для libpng (т.е. ее установку никто не отменял). Пример кода выглядит следующим образом:

```
#include <png++/png.hpp>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    png::image<png::rgb_pixel> image { argv[1] };

    std::cout << "           widht: " << image.get_width()  << '\n'
              << "          height: " << image.get_height() << '\n'
              << "compression type: " << image.get_compression_type() << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

Что касается установки: попробовал установить через conan - получил ошибки с невнятным описанием, отписался дистрибьютору пакета; в cmake-файле Вы можете использовать [find_package](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_package.html) для libpng, но не для png++, поэтому лично я пошел по пути наименьшего сопротивления - вот мой cmake-файл:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.14)
project(test_app)

set(SYS_LIB_DIR /usr/local/lib)

add_executable(test_app main.cpp)
target_compile_options(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE
    -std=c++11 -I/usr/local/include)

target_link_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE
    ${SYS_LIB_DIR})

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE
    png)
```

Некрасиво, но работает.