# Проблема с Bitmap Palette 8bpp indexed (Window xp)

Tags: c#, изображения, bitmap, png, bitmapimage

Всем доброго времени суток.
Работаю с 8-битными индексированными изображениями в формате png.
Стояла задача скопировать палитру из одного изображения и применить к другому.

```
 Bitmap first = new Bitmap("source/img1.png");
 Bitmap second = new Bitmap("source/img2.png");
 ColorPalette fp = first.Palette;
 second.Palette = fp;
 second.Save("source/img2.2.png");
```

И вот проблема. Этот код был написан из под windows 10 в Visual Studio 2019.
Проект собран с .Net Framework 4.0 x86 (Чтобы работал на Windows xp)
На Windows 10 всё отрабатывает правильно, но попробовав запустить собранный проект на Windows xp выясняется что вышеприведенный участок кода не работает. (Т.е. палитра не применяется ко второму изображению). 
Скачивал даже Visual Studio 2010 устанавливал на виртуальную машину Win Xp, пробовал написать то-же самое, но опять же из этого ничего не вышло. Палитра не применилась ко второму изображению.

Может у кого-то имеются идеи по данному вопросу, почему так происходит? Буду премного благодарен.

Comment: Извиняюсь за оффтопик, но могу только искренне посочувствовать тем, кто вынужден писать под WinXP в 2019 году. Вот тут кстати пишут о том, что нужно переиндексировать цвета: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51111141/5752652 - попробуйте, может подойдёт?

Comment: Ещё "нестандартный" вариант для экспертов, в png можно прочесть таблицу чанков, и если чанк с палитрой имеет одинаковую (возможно меньше равно прокатит) длинну, то можно тупо заменить в файле чанк с палитрой - таким образом её подменить. Остальные чанки оставить без изменений. Для этого не нужно полностью разбирать чанки, нужно только распознать эти куски. http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/236813/%d0%a7%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%ba-idat-%d1%84%d0%be%d1%80%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b0-png-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b3%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b7%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-png/772266

Comment: У bitmap есть свой хандл HBITMAP (ф-ция GetHbitmap), он совместим с WINAPI. Рекомендую для XP поэксперементировать с палитрой на с++ используя WinAPI GDI (или GDIPlus которая портирована на с# в достаточном обьеме), а затем вы сможете портировать это решение на c#

Comment: Всем большое спасибо за советы. Буду пробовать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Найдено решение) использовать LockBits.
Если сделать так:

```
Bitmap first = new Bitmap("source/img1.png");
Bitmap second = new Bitmap("source/img2.png");
ColorPalette fp = first.Palette;
second.Palette = fp;
GraphicsUnit gu = new GraphicsUnit();
int width = Convert.ToInt32(second.GetBounds(ref gu).Width);
int height = Convert.ToInt32(second.GetBounds(ref gu).Height);
BitmapData data = second.LockBits(new Rectangle(Point.Empty, second.Size), System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed);
second.UnlockBits(data);
second.Save("test.png");
```

то всё применяется и работает. Всем спасибо за помощь)